# resize video proportionally to its container

Tags: javascript, html, css, plyr.js

I need to set up a video width/height accordingly to its container.
Basically the video should have height 100% of its green container and the width should be variable.

```js
plyr.setup();
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

.plyr {
height: 100%;
  width :100%;
}

#wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  width: 900px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/2.0.11/plyr.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div data-type="youtube" data-video-id="5p-Jdjo7sSQ"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't link to your code on 3rd party sites as those links can become dead over time and then  your question will be meaningless here.

Comment: In general, if you only want one direction to be fixed and the other to adjust to remain proportional, you just set the one that is fixed and do not specify anything about the other.

Comment: You have a fixed height to 500px, apply it too to the iframe. here is the code generated by your script : `<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div tabindex="0" class="plyr plyr--youtube plyr--video"><div class="plyr__video-wrapper plyr__video-embed"><iframe  ...... width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe></div></div> 
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks I am aware of it, but unfortunately  does not work using plyr.

Comment: It is better to make a parent div with padding-bottom to a percentage of the video ratio. If youtube it is `16:9` and the padding percentage is ` 56.25%` with height `0`. Then make the iframe position `absolute` with height `100%`, width `100%`, top `0` and left `0`. This will scale the video from desktop to mobile proportionally.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution :
add other class for player's generated html.

```js
plyr.setup();
```

```css
body {
margin: 0;
}
.plyr {
height: 100%;
width :100%;
}
#wrapper{
display: flex;
justify-content:center;
width: 900px;
height: 500px;
background-color: green;
}
.plyr__video-wrapper {
height: 100%;
}
.plyr__video-wrapper iframe {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/2.0.11/plyr.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div data-type="youtube" data-video-id="5p-Jdjo7sSQ"></div> 
</div>
```

Then your height/width percents will actually perfectly work.

Answer (score 0):

Under *#wrapper*, if you remove

```
display: flex;
```

Then your height/width percents will actually work. Then you can change the width to however you'd like in your JS.

Comment: Yes Scott, I did. He had a link to the CodePen and it works if you try it where he posted - https://codepen.io/gibbok/pen/ZaBopR/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egz6bz6w/)

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.plyr {
height: 100%;
  width :100%;
}

#wrapper{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.plyr__video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.plyr__video-wrapper iframe {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```